# Listen to KeyStrokes from all the pages in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events

What exactly I am trying to do is add on more shortcuts to Google Chrome browser. As of now I am using `window.addEventListener('keyup', keyCheck, false);`.
I post a message then to the background page to carry out the relevant task.

I wonder if there is a way to achieve this when the current tab doesn't show any proper page (like newtab page, or extensions page, downloads page etc..)?

Comment: Are you writing a webpage or an extension?

Comment: I am writing an extension! Sorry I wasnt much specific..

Comment: wait, how coud you 'post a message' to a background page and from what? From a popup or?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You currently cannot inject any scripts in chrome://* pages or about:* pages that includes newtab, extensions, version, etc.

An example on how you can do keyboard shortcuts would be something like this:

[[source]](http://github.com/mohamedmansour/chrome-extensions/blob/master/reload_all_tabs/keyboard_handler.js)

```
if (window == top) {
  window.addEventListener("keyup", keyListener, false);
}

// Keyboard keyup listener callback.
function keyListener(e) {
  // Must press ctrl key to validate.
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode && !e.metaKey) {
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({
      code: e.keyCode,
      alt: e.altKey,
      shift: e.shiftKey
    });
  }
}
```

You can override those pages, but that would be an ugly fix.

Comment: Mohamed, Thanks for replying! But can you tell me what exactly are you trying to do by 'if (window == top)' ?

Comment: So you can add the 'keyup' listener on the page not for the frames inside the page. if (window == top) is for checking noframes.